# Find MGF for from PDF

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, moment-generating-functions

Let X a random variable with pdf:
$$f(y)=\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{y\pi}}e^{-\theta y}, y,\theta>0$$
Find the MGF.

I tried to solve it as follows:

let $u=\sqrt{x}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}dy=2du$

$$M(t)=\int_0^\infty e^{ty}\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{y\pi}}e^{-\theta y}dy=2\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-(\theta-t)u^2}du$$

And completing the integral as $N(0,\sigma^2=(2(\theta-t))^{-1})$:
$$M(t)=\frac{\sqrt{\theta}}{\sqrt{\theta-t}}$$

It's correct?

Comment: Because the Gaussian integral you had was only half-sided and hence equal to $\frac 12$.

Comment: For answer checking, you may see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution as it is a gamma pdf with $\displaystyle \alpha = \frac {1} {2}$. To obtain the mgf you do not need to use transformation; just use the fact that the pdf integrate to $1$ (Gamma integral)